# I am unable to run an Angular app on xammp

Tags: angular

I am just starting to learn Angular. I have setup the project on a xammp server in windows. Here is my project structure:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\loginAngular
```

Inside the loginAngular folder are:

```
1)app
2)node_modules
3)typings
4)index.html
```

My index file looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get this error in my console:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/app/main.js"
```

Comment: inside folder `app`, is there a file called `main.js`?

Comment: yes, main.js present inside app folder

Answer (score 0):

change `<base href="/">`  to `<base href="./">` to make your paths relative to `http://localhost/loginAngular` instead of to `http://localhost`

Answer (score 0):

change `<base href="/">` to

`<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>`